# Sudden problem with Playwright on Chrome?

Tags: playwright, playwright-dotnet

I had some code that was previously (like a week ago) working that hasn't changed, but the system under test has and I've upgraded Chrome.

Now sometimes when I execute ScrollIntoViewIfNeeded the first one seems to work, but later calls to it do this:

```
=========================== logs ===========================
  waiting for element to be  and stable
  element is  and stable
  element is not displayed, retrying in 0ms
  waiting for element to be  and stable
  element is  and stable
  element is not displayed, retrying in 50ms
  waiting for element to be  and stable
  element is  and stable
  element is not displayed, retrying in 100ms
  waiting for element to be  and stable
  element is  and stable
```

`element is  and stable` seems like it's missing something when formatting the logging at the very least.

I tried using different elements to scroll into view, but the behavior seems consistent.  Since the playwright version hasn't changed I'm wondering if there's a compatibility issue with a newer version of Chrome (I'm on 116).

I should also mention the first element (where it works) is a scroll down on the page, and the others are scroll ups.  It doesn't seem like that should matter, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Is anyone else seeing this or just me?

Comment: Generally with a change in chrome version,  a correspondence playwright version also comes